# Only check Django form if radio button is selected

Tags: django, forms

I got one form in a Django checkout page where the user can select if their product is gonna be shipped to the regular address ou another one he/she desires.

The case is: if the user uses the regular address, some fields do not need to be filled. Otherwise, if the costumer selects to be shipped to another address, Django must check if all form fields are properly filled.

My form.py:

```
class ProfileRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('date_of_birth', 'cep', 'rua', 'numero', 'bairro',
                  'complemento', 'cidade', 'estado')

        labels = {'date_of_birth': 'Data de nascimento',
                  'cep': 'CEP',
                  'numero': 'Nº'}

        widgets = {'date_of_birth': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'date_of_birth',
                                                           'OnKeyPress': 'formatar("##/##/##", this)',
                                                           'maxlength': "8",
                                                           'placeholder': '__/__/__', 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'cep': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'cep',
                                                 'onblur': 'pesquisacep(this.value)',
                                                 'OnKeyPress': 'formatar("#####-###", this)',
                                                 'placeholder': '______-___',
                                                 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'rua': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'id': 'rua', 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'bairro': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'id': 'bairro', 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'cidade': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'id': 'cidade', 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'estado': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'id': 'uf', 'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'numero': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'numero', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Nº'}),
                   'complemento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'complemento', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Complemento'}),}
```

The checkout.html template:

```
  <form action="" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
            <div id="user-info">
                <p><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>, confira abaixo o endereço de entrega:</p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="address" checked="checked"> Endereço de entrega:<br>
                    {{ user.profile.rua }}, nº {{ user.profile.numero }} - {{ user.profile.complemento }}<br>
                    {{ user.profile.bairro }}<br>
                    {{ user.profile.cidade}}/{{ user.profile.estado }}<br>
                    CEP: {{ user.profile.cep }}

                </p>
            </div>


            <div id="shipping-info">
                <hr>
                <p><input type="radio" name="address">
                    Desejo alterar o endereço de recebimento:</p>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.cep.label_tag }} {{ address_form.cep }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.rua }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.numero }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.complemento }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.cidade }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    {{ address_form.estado }}
                </div>
                <hr>


                    {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class="form-group">

                      <label for="card-element">Insira as informações do seu cartão de crédito:</label>

                    <div id="card-element" class="form-control">

                    </div>


                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Finalizar a compra">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Is there any chance that Django checks the another address fields only if the user has checked the second radio button?

I know I can do this making form field manually and then checking all the fields in the views. But I'm wondering if this could be solved inside the forms.py.

Just to illustrate the currente checkout webpage:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `clean` method to run your form validation.

I would also change your radio button to be part of the form and not raw HTML in the template. Maybe even make it a checkbox or select box if it's easier that way.

I have a form which works in a very similar way, providing an option for addresses to do shipping and billing.

Below is a sample of the clean method, in it `billing_address_choice` is a choice field which allows a user to select 'new' for a new address or select from addresses already in the system. If the choice is 'new' then it does a check to make sure the billing fields contain data.

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Custom form cleaning
    """
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    billing_address_choice = cleaned_data.get('billing_address_choice')
    if billing_address_choice == 'new':
        # a new billing address has been entered, enforce required-ness
        for field in (
                'billing_address1',
                'billing_city',
                'billing_state',
                'billing_country',
                'billing_postcode',
        ):
            if not cleaned_data.get(field):
                self.add_error(field, _('This field is required'))
```

The docs on form validation can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/